# How to use 'file_get_contents('php://input');' to return data on localhost

Tags: php

I Am using localhost server to store response from mpesa Daraja gateway api but unfortunately I can get back the response using

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Any help especially on integration of Daraja Mpesa gateway for C2B

Comment: Share some code...

Comment: $data=Json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$name=$data['name'];

Apply this code on both get and post.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please consider referring to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that we may better assist you.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that when working with the Daraja API you need your endpoint to be **publicly accessible**. Localhost is only accessible from your machine which means Daraja won't be able to send over data to you.

So this means you may need to have a domain eg `https://www.mycompany.com` and then your url `https://www.mycompany.com/api/gateway` that points to your hosted application.

Also, to get the contents of the request that the callback receives, you use:

```
$data=Json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Whose details you can go through like so:

```
$transactionTime = $data['TransTime'];
```